# Insertion of data into Database

Tags: php, html-table

[image]//Connection.php

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'faculty_corner';

$link = mysqli_init();
$success = mysqli_real_connect( $link, $host, $user, $password, $db);

if ($success == TRUE) {
    echo 'KUDOS !!! Connected to Database';
} 
?>
```

//varpay.php (the page from where I want the data to be sent to db)

//insert statement: in this form I have put fid as an autoincrement and calculation = NULL as I have a view button there which lets me to go to next page 'p1.php'

```
<pre>
<?php

if ($_POST['submit'] == 1){

$sql = "INSERT INTO `faculty_corner`.`tabdata` (fid, `facname`, `designation`, basic, varper, varamt, appamt, calculation) VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[facname]', '$_POST[designation]', $_POST[basic], $_POST[varper], $_POST[varamt], $_POST[appamt], NULL)";

if(mysqli_query($success, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);

}

?>
</pre>

<form action="varpay.php" method="post">
<table name="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="border-top-left-radius:10px;">S.no</th>
      <th>Faculty Name</th>
      <th>Designation</th>
      <th>Basic AMt.</th>
      <th>Var %</th>
      <th>Var Amt.</th>
      <th>Approved Aoount.</th>
      <th style="border-top-right-radius:10px;">Calculation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="width:60px;" name="fid">1</td>
      <td><input name="facname" type="text" class="boxin" type="number"/></td>
      <td align="center" style="width:60px;" ><input type="text" name="designation" class="boxin"/></td>
      <td align="center"><input name="basic" class="boxin" type="number"/></td>
      <td align="center"><input name="varper" class="boxon" type="number"/></td>      
      <td align="center"><input name="varamt" class="boxin" type="number" value="" /></td>
      <td align="center"><input name="appamt" class="boxin" type="number" value="" /></td>
      <td align="center"><a href="p1.php"><input type="button" name="calculation" value="view"/></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan="8" align="center"><button type="submit" name="submit"> SUBMIT </button></td></tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

This is my error.

Comment: In any question, you should mention what goes wrong exactly. Which exact error message do you get? Or does it act like it worked, but the wrong data got written etc. Please edit thge question and add that in.

Comment: Am extremely sorry for that actually i dont know the rules I am very new here. and i have updated my question now

My error image is in this link 'enter image description here'

Comment: *This is my error.* What Error ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar The error is in the OP's screen shot. "Undefined index: submit"

Comment: @MrLister: He updated his question. He didn't wrote the full code before. Only insertion part.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no need mentioning fid if it is an auto-increment column. Second of all you are inconsistent with using '. 
Try replacing the query with this version:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `faculty_corner`.`tabdata` (facname, designation, basic, varper, varamt, appamt) VALUES ('$_POST[facname]', '$_POST[designation]', '$_POST[basic]', '$_POST[varper]', '$_POST[varamt]', '$_POST[appamt]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all post values `$_POST[SomeName]` to `$_POST['SomeName']`. You are missing `'` inside `square bracket []`.

For auto increment, just change `column fid` to `primary key` and `auto-increment` in your database table. It will automatically get increment.

I've updated my code. Please have a look.

```
<?
$sql = "INSERT INTO `faculty_corner`.`tabdata` (`fid`, `facname`, `designation`, `basic`, `varper`, `varamt`, `appamt`, `calculation`) 
        VALUES (NULL, '".$_POST['facname']."', '".$_POST['designation']."', '".$_POST['basic']."', '".$_POST['varper']."', '".$_POST['varamt']."', '."$_POST['appamt']".', NULL)";

?>
```